# Как изменить файл на удаленном компьютере?

Tags: python

Имеется:

- На удаленном компьютере(Linux) лежит файл.
- строка с данными.

Необходимо:

- подключиться к компьютеру,
- прочитать данный файл. Если в файле имеется искомая строка с данными, то завершаем выполнение, иначе добавляем строку в конец файла.

Чтение файла, поиск и добавление строки - сделал, на локальном компьютере работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проделать все это на удаленном компьютере?

Comment: Ну а как скрипт на локальном компьютере связан с удалённым компьютером? Что находится на удалённом компьютере?

Comment: Наверное, проще всего небольшой веб-сервис на Flask написать, как обычно. И обращаться с запросом по http

Comment: @nightflash. На удаленном компьютере например файл с кодами. Мне в скрипте нужно проверить есть ли код в файле на удаленном компе и если нет, то добавить код.

Comment: @CrazyElf, нужен просто одиночный скрипт.

Comment: @xakslim Так а как вы собираетесь зайти на сервер? Через какой протокол? Просто так вам никакой сервер не даст доступ к своим файлам.

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну вот в этом то и вопрос. Как лучше это сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если по простому делать,
то можно использовать что-то от @Даниил_Чижевский или `rsync`:
скачали-обработали-закачали.

Но возможны сложные случаи:

Если один и тот же скрипт запускается одновременно несколько раз,
например из веб сервера с разными искомыми строками,
то в файле в результате окажется непонятно что.

Если взломают компьютер со скриптом, могут получить доступ и к удаленному с файлом.

Так что задача может усложниться до своего веб сервиса на удаленном компьютере:

- с API (POST /add-str)
- с проверкой доступа.
- с блокировкaми файла (`flock`) или базой данных с *атомарной* операцией.

Answer (score 1):

"Родной" протокол для передачи информации между серверами `Linux` - `SSH`. Также существует протокол `SFTP` - он работает поверх `SSH` и позволяет передавать файлы или информацию о них.

Для `Python` существует модуль `PySftp` - он хоть и староват, но вполне работоспособен. Документацию по модулю можно найти на `PyPi`: https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/.

Comment: Unix, GNU/Linux, OpenBSD, Solaris, Aix, FreeBSD и тд. Для примера "Родного" протокола нет по умолчанию на ванилином Debian.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh user@host "if ! grep icq /path/to/file; then echo appendix >> /path/to/file; fi"
```

- логинимся на `host` как пользователь `user`
- проверяем при помощи `grep` наличие строки, которая содержит `icq`
- в случае, если `grep` не нашел строку, добавляем в конец файла `appendix`.

Без питона но логика тут такая - на удаленном хосте должен работать хоть какой-то сервис sshd, Apache, ftpd и тд.

В случае sshd у пользователя должны быть права на чтение запись в желаемый файл.